# How to get different counting lables for different grouped pictures?

Tags: graphics, labels, best-practices

I was thing something along these lines:

blabla

**picture of a gold fish**

Fish 1: gold fish

blabla

**picture of a dog**

Mammal 1: dog

blabla

**picture of a shark**

Fish 2: shark

blabla

**picture of a horse**

Mammal 2: hores

...

---

In stead of all having this *figure x* in front. But it should count automatically.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Show what you have tried so far and what problems you are facing by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: If you want to use \caption, you will need to create new float types (newfloat or float packages).  Either that or swap counters and change \captionsetup each time.